# Removing right-command as "show desktop"

Tags: mac, keyboard, desktop

I just got my Mac several months ago, and set my right-command as `show desktop` shortcut. Now, I want to remove it, but I totally forget how to remove this silly thing. I have checked several places as shown in the images below, but both shows that `show desktop` shortcut is `F11`, and I don't know where else should I find the configuration where I set my right-command as the `show desktop`, so could anyone help me?

PS: I use OS X Lion 10.7.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to see a cool trick? Press `⌘ Command` + `⇧ Shift` + `4` (use the 4 on the number row, you cannot use the number pad if you have one). Your cursor will change to a crosshair. Press the spacebar and it turns into a camera. Hover over the window, and click. Now, look for a 'Screen Shot PNG' file on your desktop.

You're welcome :).

Comment: @Jason: out of topic and I already used that to make this post...

Comment: No, you didn't use that, at least not all of it. The fact that your screenshots (1) don't preserve the rounded windows edges and (2) have other window data underneath the system preferences window means that you did not do what I suggested. I was merely making a suggestion about an easier way of cutting making amazingly clean screenshots. It's not 'off topic'.

Comment: okay I didn't use the spacebar... I would still say that it's totally OOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who like me didn't find the right answer ;-).
I accidentially turned on "Show desktop" on left "Command" key.
It has nothing to do with "Keyboard shortcuts" preference!

Go to "Preferences" -> "Mission Control" and change "Show Desktop" key from listbox to something useful.

Remember even if it doesn't show "left Command" key it uses it ;-), so change it.

Comment: after checking several times, this does work for me... weird

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This was bugging me for the day.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences does not allow you to assign the 'meta' keys by themselves (command, option, shift, control) to take some sort of action, I believe you installed some sort of third party program to set this up.

The first one that I could think of would probably be [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), but there are many other apps that it could be.

I would suggest that you review the icons located in your menu bar, and see if any of them have to do with keyboard customization.

[image: Various icons in the menu bar]

Comment: Off topic: icons are for Skype, Cyberduck, don't know, don't know, Divvy, Wifi Bluetooth, Sound

Comment: Skype, Adium, Alfred, SMART Reporter, Divvy, WiFi, Bluetooth, Sound, Time and Date, Fast User Switching, Spotlight

Comment: @StuWilson You picked the wrong duck :).

Comment: there's no such a software in my mac... this thing confuses me...

Answer (score 1):

There is a second place (at least in Ventura) to configure this behaviour:

- Open System Settings -> Desktop & Dock
- Scroll to the very bottom, and click on 'Shortcuts...' (which is actually under another set of 'Mission Control' settings)
- A small window will popup, the last/bottom option defines the 'Show Desktop' keyboard shortcut
- Change that thing to anything you want, F11 seems to be a safe choice

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Maciej fixed it for me (can't comment or vote because I'm too new). 'Show Desktop' in Mission Control was set to F11, but left command still showed desktop. Set show desktop to left command, tested, then back to F11, and tested again.

All fixed, left command is back to normal.